# How to throttle often re-rendered component in react

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, throttling

I want to throttle rendering component which connects to WS and often gets data, which cause its very often re-render.
There is my solution with `useMemo` hook but I'm not sure that `useMemo` is designed for such things.
For sure every update of `data` will cause re-render because is that how `useState` works, and I have to update this `data` state.
Do you have maybe some advices or ideas how to throttle re-renders of `<DataVisualizator />` Component?

`useInterval hook`

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const useInterval = (callback: () => void, delay: number) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef<() => void>();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      if (savedCallback.current) {
        savedCallback.current();
      }
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};
```

And component which receive data and should throttle his children

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import useWebSocket from "react-use-websocket";
import { useInterval } from "../Hooks";

export const WebSockets = () => {
  const SOCKET_URL = "wss://someWS";
  //data will be kind of Dictionary .eg { "key1": val, "anotherkey: valOther }
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const webSocketOptions = {
    shouldReconnect: () => true,
    retryOnError: true,
    reconnectInterval: 3000,
    reconnectAttempts: 5,
    onError: (e) => console.log(e),
  };

  const { sendMessage, lastMessage } = useWebSocket(
    SOCKET_URL,
    webSocketOptions
  );

  const handleData = (message: RequestData, data: OrderBookData) => {
    // lot of operations to deepClone state and set new with new Data
    setData(clonedData);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    lastMessage && handleData(JSON.parse(lastMessage.data), data);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [lastMessage]);

  const [tickThrottle, setTickThrottle] = useState(false);
  useInterval(() => {
    setTickThrottle(!tickThrottle);
  }, 700);

  //Throttling with useMemo hook
  const throttledDataVisdsualizator = useMemo(
    () => <DataVisualizator dataToVisualize={data} />,
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [tickThrottle]
  );
  return (
    <>
        {throttledDataVisdsualizator}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `useMemo` hook

```
  const [tickThrottle, setTickThrottle] = useState(false);
  useInterval(() => {
    setTickThrottle(!tickThrottle);
  }, 700);

  //Throttling with useMemo hook
  const throttledDataVisdsualizator = useMemo(
    () => <DataVisualizator dataToVisualize={data} />,
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [tickThrottle]
  );
  return (
    <>
        {throttledDataVisdsualizator}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: This will only throttle things if `data` is always a new object though; if `data` is internally modified, those changes will be rendered.

Comment: @AKX yes, data Will be always new object, inside of `handleData` I do deepClone of current state and setting modified deep clone as new, so data is always new object